# How to do when the activity back to the background forced to redraw the view

Tags: android

Help！
I want to re-draw the page in the app back to the background, but the addView method does not work, the system did not call the onDraw method。

I tried calling the invalidate method and the requestLayout method, but it did not have any effect. Is there any way to solve it? Here is the main code.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
FragmentLayout view1 = (FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView();

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            addRenderScriptBitmap();
        }
    });
    getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
    getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();

}


private void addRenderScriptBitmap() {
    view1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view1.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = view1.getDrawingCache();

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    imageView.setImageBitmap(renderScriptBitmap(bitmap, MainActivity.this, 16.f));
    view1.addView(imageView);//This method does not work
}

public Bitmap renderScriptBitmap(Bitmap sentBitmap, Context context, float radius) {
    Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);


    final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, sentBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
            Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    final Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
    final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    script.setRadius(radius /* e.g. 3.f */);
    script.setInput(input);
    script.forEach(output);
    output.copyTo(bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

I want the application to fall back into the background when it becomes like this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0CN6.png)

Comment: android :not allows you to update view when application is in background

Comment: I want the application to fall back into the background when it becomes like this：enter image description [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0CN6.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
    super.onResume(); 
    handler.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override 
        public void run() 
        { 
            addRenderScriptBitmap(); 
        } 
    }); 
    getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();
    getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: I want the application to fall back into the background when it becomes like this：enter image description [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0CN6.png)